# array search and display

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have a function that searches through an array of vegetable varieties to see if it matches an ID:

```
// my function
function findVariety($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array))
    {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value)
            $results[] = $array;

        foreach ($array as $subarray)
            $results = array_merge($results, findVariety($subarray, $key, $value));
    }
    return $results;
}
// function call
$picks = findVariety($veg,id,$sf->spring_choice);
```

when successful, it returns something like this:

```
// returned from print_r($picks);
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [variety] => Royal Burgundy (bush) ) )
```

All I'm missing is how to add the variety to an echo that I'm sending to my page, Ex:

```
echo '<td height="90px">'.$picks['variety'] .'<br /><a href="#" onclick="fill_square('.$a.','.$b.','.$box->id.','.$ID.');">add plants</a></td>';
```

As of now, I have been stuck on this last step! Any help would be amazing...

Comment: It looks like that value is at: `$picks[0]['variety']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returned array is nested so to access the variety you'd need to do this:

```
echo $picks[0]['variety']
```

Comment: when I tried echo $picks[0]['variety'] it didn't return anything for some reason?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't being output, have you checked the source of the HTML?

Comment: I have indeed... the only way I've managed to get it to display anything is with print_r($picks)

Comment: this is the line I am trying to display:echo '<td height="90px">'.$picks[0]['varity'].'<br /><a href="#" onclick="fill_square('.$a.','.$b.','.$box->id.','.$ID.');">add plants</a></td>';

Comment: ok.. figured it out... that was the solution, I had changed something in the function that generates the array while testing and didn't change it back. works great!!